# How do I make multiple API calls in parallel to the same endpoint and combine all the responses into an output array?

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, rx-java, kotlin-coroutines

Currently in my Kotlin code, I have an array of users and I do a for loop and make GET request for each user's information and then add their information to a MutableList. I observe the list and update my UI whenever a new user info is posted to it.

But I was wondering how I could do all the user calls at the same time and await the final result and post UI all at once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`async`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/async.html) syntax to start requests and then [`awaitAll`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/await-all.html) on them (just be aware that it will fail immediately as soon as any of the deferreds fail).

Something like:

```kotlin
val one = async { doSomethingUsefulOne() }
val two = async { doSomethingUsefulTwo() }

val result = awaitAll(one, two) // will give you a list of results
```

So in your case you can [`map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) over the users and start `async` operation on them.

Example: https://kotlinexpertise.com/kotlin-coroutines-concurrency/

Roman Elisarov's blog on structured concurrency: https://elizarov.medium.com/structured-concurrency-722d765aa952 (part about parallel decomposition)